# Using Two Columns in SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

TableA

```
AID     AName
1       Alpha
2       Bravo
3       Charlie
```

TableB

```
BID     BName
1       Delta
2       Echo
3       Foxtrot
```

TableC

```
CID     AID     BID
1       1       null
2       null    2
3       3       null
```

I am using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT C.CID, A.Name AS First, B.Name AS Second FROM TableC 
INNER JOIN TableA ON TableC.AID = TableA.AID
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableC.BID = TableB.BID
```

but displays a blank record. The expected result should be:

```
CID     First     Second
1       Alpha
2                 Echo
3       Charlie
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Ohh. It was a rookie mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` for each A, B table

```
SELECT C.CID, A.AName, B.BName
FROM C
LEFT JOIN A ON C.AID = A.AID
LEFT JOIN B ON C.BID = B.BID
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT C.CID, A.Name AS First, B.Name AS Second 
FROM TableC 
LEFT JOIN TableA ON TableC.AID = TableA.AID
LEFT JOIN TableB ON TableC.BID = TableB.BID